# Angular strap select, get value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I use angular strap and my select looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
    ng-model="selectedObject" 
    data-html="1"
    bs-options="object.title for object in my_objects" bs-select>
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

my_objects array:

```
$scope.my_objects = [
    {title:'1'},
    {title:'two'},
    {title:'three'}
]
```

And when i use `{{selectedObject}}` in template, it gives me right result. But when i try to use this value in Controller, `$scope.selectedObject` is empty. How i can fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needs to create wrapper object to maintain pointer to your model.
Create a wrapper object. I have created wrapper as object and assign wrapper.selectedObject as ngModel.

Change your code to following

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
    ng-model="wrapper.selectedObject" 
    data-html="1"
    bs-options="object.title for object in my_objects" bs-select>
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```

Change your controller to followings

```
$scope.wrapper = {};

$scope.my_objects = [
    {title:'1'},
    {title:'two'},
    {title:'three'}
];
```